# how remove every thing from a list except words?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
my_list=["'-\\n'",
 "'81\\n'",
 "'-\\n'",
 "'0913\\n'",
 "'Assistant nursing\\n'",
 "'0533\\n'",
 "'0895 Astronomy\\n'",
 "'0533\\n'",
 "'Astrophysics\\n'",
 "'0532\\n'"]
```

Is there any way to delete every thing from this list except words?

out put:

```
my_list=['Assistant nursing',
 'Astronomy',
 'Astrophysics',]
```

I know for example if i wanna remove integers in string form i can do this:

```
no_integers = [x for x in my_list if not (x.isdigit() 
                                         or x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit())]
```

but it dosn't work well enough

Comment: You're probably looking for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: for items included text and number how I can remove numbers ?

Comment: You need to *specify* what you mean by "words".  You need to partition your strings according to that definition.  You need to test those partitions for "word-ness", and keep only those that meet your specifications.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  You've neglected to give a clear problem definition, and to supply code that addresses that definition.

Comment: Why do the strings also contain literal quote and newline characters? Maybe you should clean up the data when you're creating the list in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **non-regex** solution:

You can start by striping off the characters `'-\\n`, then take only the characters that are alphabets using `str.isalpha` or a white space, then filter out the sub-strings that are empty `''`. You may need to strip off the white space characters in the end, whic

```py
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x!='', (''.join(j for j in i.strip('\'-\\\\n') if j.isalpha() or j==' ').strip() for i in my_list)))

['Assistant nursing', 'Astronomy', 'Astrophysics']
```

If you want to use **regex**, you can use the pattern: `'([A-Za-z].*?)\\\\n'`  with `re.findall`, then filter out the elements that are empty list, finally you can flatten the list

```py
>>> import re
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x, [re.findall('([A-Za-z].*?)\\\\n', i) for i in my_list]))
[['Assistant nursing'], ['Astronomy'], ['Astrophysics']]
```

Comment: It remove spaces between words contained 2 parts.

Answer (score 0):

with regular expresssions

```
import re

my_list = # above
# remove \n, -, digits, ' symbols
my_new_list = [re.sub(r"[\d\\n\-']", '', s) for s in my_list]
# remove empty strings
my_new_list = [s for s in my_new_list if s != '']

print(my_new_list)
```

Output

```
['Assistat ursig', ' Astroomy', 'Astrophysics']
```